# WPF TextBlock Style влияет на стиль TextBlock в ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Проблема следующая: в `App.xaml` переопределяю стиль для всех `TextBlock` в программе. Всё работает прекрасно, но этот стиль также оказывает влияние на тексты в `ComboBox`. Т.е. при изменении цвета в стиле `TextBlock`, меняется и цвет в самом `ComboBox`.

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
</Style>
```

Что бы я ни делал с `ComboBox` после кода выше, его цвет больше не поменяется. Переопределять отображение элементов в `ComboBox` не стоит на повестке дня. Вопрос в следующем. Есть ли какой-то способ жёстко указать в `ComboBox` цвет текста? Если в программе создать код подобным тому, что представлен ниже, то цвет текста будет зелёным, хотя я жёстко задал, что должен быть красным.

```xml
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" Foreground="Red">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Test Item" />
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Назначьте стилю `x:Key="MyTextBlockStyle"` и используйте явно в текстблоках `Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"`, тогда там где стиль не подключен - он не будет применяться.

Comment: Конечно это решение мне известно, но, если у меня 100+ таких текстовых полей. Получается, нужно побродить по всему проекту и везде указать это. Мне-то необходимо сделать одно общее решение.

Comment: Если так не хотите `Переопределять отображение элементов в ComboBox не стоит на повестке дня.` и так не хотите `Назначьте стилю x:Key`, то у меня решения для вас нет. Еще можно взболтать, но не смешивать, например вы назначите ключ, а в родительских контролах, где нужно применить стиль ко все текстблокам, например `StackPanel.Resources` заведите стиль `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"/>`, тогда стиль будет применен только во всех дочерних текстблоках.

Comment: Кстати, по поводу 100+, если у вас проект по сложности не размером с VisualStudio, то у вас не должно быть их даже 40 штук. Если у вас действительно их столько, то что-то пошло не так, например вы не используете привязки к коллекциям и шаблоны, и у вас много где повторяется однотипная разметка групп контролов. А если код или разметка повторяется - значит вы нарушили принцип разработки DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself, подумайте, как это можно исправить.

Comment: Глобальное переопределение стиля `TextBlock` — очень плохая идея. `TextBlock` используется везде, и ваше переопределение меняет его везде. Меняйте локально, только в тех блоках, где вам нужно.